# Events imported by URL to Google Calendar appear as busy & private

Tags: ruby, google-calendar-api, icalendar

Attempting to import by URL the following `ics` data by calling an endpoint on an API I'm working on. Google does import the events at the required time and date, but their title is `busy` and status `Private` even though the events contain `CLASS:PUBLIC`. Using [icalendar ruby gem](https://github.com/icalendar/icalendar) to build the ical data.

Also, the API responds with `Content-Type: text/calendar` header. Trying to import the data below through a file format works fine. The problem is in the URL import. Did not try Outlook/iCalendar. No solutions from other stackoverflow threads worked so far.

Any thoughts as to what might be the problem?

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:icalendar-ruby
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
METHOD:PUBLISH
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTAMP:20191120T143449Z
UID:4a22a9b7-8b20-487b-a4fb-bc0b6ff90adf
DTSTART:20191121T070000
DTEND:20191121T130000
CLASS:PUBLIC
SUMMARY:7a Driver
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTAMP:20191120T143449Z
UID:5eda6340-bfec-417e-869a-d5f1af2ba433
DTSTART:20191122T070000
DTEND:20191122T130000
CLASS:PUBLIC
SUMMARY:7a Driver
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Comment: I bet it’d be faster and more appropriate to ask in `icalendar` issue tracker.

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem with the icalendar ruby gem.

I've created a sample ICS file like this:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//Google Inc//Google Calendar 70.9054//EN
VERSION:2.0
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
METHOD:PUBLISH
X-WR-CALNAME:email@domain.com
X-WR-TIMEZONE:Europe/Madrid
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART:20191120T160000Z
DTEND:20191120T170000Z
DTSTAMP:20191120T162746Z
UID:<id>@domain.com
CLASS:PUBLIC
CREATED:20191120T162722Z
DESCRIPTION:busy
LAST-MODIFIED:20191120T162722Z
LOCATION:
SEQUENCE:0
STATUS:CONFIRMED
SUMMARY:event 1
TRANSP:OPAQUE
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART:20191120T173000Z
DTEND:20191120T183000Z
DTSTAMP:20191120T162746Z
UID:<another-id>@domain.com
CLASS:PRIVATE
CREATED:20191120T162733Z
DESCRIPTION:private
LAST-MODIFIED:20191120T162733Z
LOCATION:
SEQUENCE:0
STATUS:CONFIRMED
SUMMARY:event 2
TRANSP:TRANSPARENT
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

## Events

### Event 1

- CLASS:PUBLIC
- TRANSP:OPAQUE

Meaning that it's a public event and I will be considered "Busy" during it.

### Event 2

- CLASS:PRIVATE
- TRANSP:TRANSPARENT

Meaning that it's a private event and I will be considered "Free" during it.

## Solution

I'd recommend you head to the [library's Issue Tracker](https://github.com/icalendar/icalendar/issues) and file a bug report there.